# Room DB join table A to table B and B to C using @Relation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

This seems to be a vary basic query but i am not able to achieve through relation.

Let's Say Table A need to join with Table B

```
data class MasterQuery{
 @Embedded var tableA: TableA,
 @Relation(
    parentColumn = "table_a_relation",
    entityColumn = "table_b_details"
 )
 val tableB: TableB
}
```

Now How do we join TableB to TableC? and get MasterQuery result from all three tables.

First can't put embedded and relation on same field.

Then this also fails -

```
data class MasterQuery{
 @Embedded var tableA: TableA,
 @Relation(
    parentColumn = "table_a_relation",
    entityColumn = "table_b_details",
    entity = SubQuery::class)
   val subQuery: SubQuery
 }

 @Entity
 data class SubQuery{
   @Embedded var tableB: TableB,
   @Relation(
    parentColumn = "table_b_relation",
    entityColumn = "table_c_details"
 )
  val tableC: TableC
 }
```

Error can't find SubQuery.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these corrections to you classes:

```
data class MasterQuery{
 @Embedded var tableA: TableA,
 @Relation(
    parentColumn = "table_a_relation",
    entityColumn = "table_b_details",
    //entity = SubQuery::class) <---- 1. replace this with TableB class
    entity = TableB::class) 
   val subQuery: SubQuery
 }

 //@Entity  <---- 2. You don't need this
 data class SubQuery{
   @Embedded var tableB: TableB,
   @Relation(
    parentColumn = "table_b_relation",
    entityColumn = "table_c_details"
 )
  val tableC: TableC
 }
```